# SQL Server XML Column - Result free of Concat

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have an xml column in my SQL Server database that has records in the following format

```
<items>
<item>
      <data alias="Number">123N</data> 
      <data alias="Description">4 sq.mm Feed Through Terminal block in Grey colour</data>   
      <data alias="Standard Packing Quantity">100</data> 
 </item>
 <item>
      <data alias="Number">234N</data> 
      <data alias="Description">Toy</data> 
      <data alias="Standard Packing Quantity">100</data> 
 </item>
 <item>
      <data alias="Number">579N</data> 
      <data alias="Description">Doll</data> 
      <data alias="Standard Packing Quantity">100</data> 
 </item>
 <item>
      <data alias="Catalouge Number">234</data> 
      <data alias="Description">Vehicle</data> 
      <data alias="Standard Packing Quantity">324234</data> 
 </item>
 </items>
```

So to extract the data here I use:

---

```
SELECT 
       CatalogueNo,Description,StdPackingQty 
       from
       (select
 CAST(xml as xml).query('//data alias=''Description'']').value('.','nvarchar(225)')   [Description],   
 CAST(xml as xml).query('//data [@alias=''Catalouge Number'']')
.value('.','nvarchar(225)')[CatalogueNo],  
 CAST(xml as xml).query('//data [@alias=''Standard Packing Quantity'']').value('.','nvarchar(225)')[StdPackingQty]
        from [dbo].[cmsContentXml] )as hierarchy
Where CatalogueNo is not null
```

---

The problem I face is that the data that is extracted is all concatenated.
I need data in   separate rows for each item,so the data needs to be in 3 
columns and 4 rows.

Kindly help me resolve the issue asap and help write a query that would fetch data 
free of concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Cross Apply` to breakdown the XML into separate data rows, and pull the data from those:

```
SELECT 
    CatalogueNo,Description,StdPackingQty 
from (
    select 
        i.value('data[@alias="Description"][1]','nvarchar(225)') [Description],
        i.value('data[@alias="Catalouge Number"][1]','nvarchar(225)') [CatalogueNo],
        i.value('data[@alias="Standard Packing Quantity"][1]','nvarchar(225)') [StdPackingQty]
    from [Connectwell].[dbo].[cmsContentXml]
    cross apply xml.nodes('/items/item') x(i)
) as hierarchy 
--Where CatalogueNo is not null
```

Note: I've remmed out the where clause at the end as it will reduce you to just one row, whereas the question state you want 4 rows as the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the order of your elements always are the same you can use `position()` to get the values:

```
select X.N.value('data[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Number,
       X.N.value('data[2]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Descritpion,
       X.N.value('data[3]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Quanatity
from @T as T
  cross apply T.XMLColumn.nodes('/items/item') as X(N)
```

Otherwise you need to get the value using `alias`. Your fourth row has an alias `"Catalouge Number"` that is different from the other rows so you can either have that as a separate column:

```
select X.N.value('data[@alias="Number"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Number,
       X.N.value('data[@alias="Catalouge Number"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as CatalougeNumber,
       X.N.value('data[@alias="Description"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Descritpion,
       X.N.value('data[@alias="Standard Packing Quantity"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Quanatity
from @T as T
  cross apply T.XMLColumn.nodes('/items/item') as X(N)
```

Or you can combine the two in the same column:

```
select X.N.value('data[@alias=("Number","Catalouge Number")][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Number,
       X.N.value('data[@alias="Description"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Descritpion,
       X.N.value('data[@alias="Standard Packing Quantity"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Quanatity
from @T as T
  cross apply T.XMLColumn.nodes('/items/item') as X(N)
```

Your where clause can be added to the queries like this:

```
where X.N.exist('data[@alias="Catalouge Number"]') = 1
```

Or if you want to check against both number aliases:

```
where X.N.exist('data[@alias=("Number","Catalouge Number")]') = 1
```

Test data:

```
declare @T table(XMLColumn xml)
insert into @T values
('<items>
<item>
      <data alias="Number">123N</data> 
      <data alias="Description">4 sq.mm Feed Through Terminal block in Grey colour</data>   
      <data alias="Standard Packing Quantity">100</data> 
 </item>
 <item>
      <data alias="Number">234N</data> 
      <data alias="Description">Toy</data> 
      <data alias="Standard Packing Quantity">100</data> 
 </item>
 <item>
      <data alias="Number">579N</data> 
      <data alias="Description">Doll</data> 
      <data alias="Standard Packing Quantity">100</data> 
 </item>
 <item>
      <data alias="Catalouge Number">234</data> 
      <data alias="Description">Vehicle</data> 
      <data alias="Standard Packing Quantity">324234</data> 
 </item>
 </items>
')
```

**Edit:**

I see that you cast your XML column to XML. That is not necessary if the column already is of data type XML so I guess you have a varchar(max) or something in there. If so you need to do like this to cast the to XML before applying `.nodes()` function:

```
select X.N.value('data[@alias=("Number","Catalouge Number")][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Number,
       X.N.value('data[@alias="Description"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Descritpion,
       X.N.value('data[@alias="Standard Packing Quantity"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Quanatity
from @T as T
  cross apply (select cast(XMLColumn as xml)) as X1(XMLColumn)
  cross apply X1.XMLColumn.nodes('/items/item') as X(N)
where X.N.exist('data[@alias=("Number","Catalouge Number")]') = 1
```

**Edit 2**

```
select xml.value('data[@alias=("Number","Catalouge Number")][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Number,
       xml.value('data[@alias="Description"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Descritpion,
       xml.value('data[@alias="Standard Packing Quantity"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Quanatity 
from [dbo].[cmsContentXml] as Hierarchy 
  cross apply (select cast(xml as xml)) as X1(xml) 
  cross apply X1.xml.nodes('/items/item') as xml(N) 
where xml.N.exist('data[@alias=("Number","Catalouge Number")]')=1
```

Comment: select xml.value('data[@alias=("Number","Catalouge Number")][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Number,xml.value('data[@alias="Description"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Descritpion,xml.value('data[@alias="Standard Packing Quantity"][1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Quanatity
 from  [dbo].[cmsContentXml] as Hierarchy
  cross apply (select cast(xml as xml)) as X1(xml)
  cross apply X1(xml).nodes('/items/item') as xml(N)
where xml.N.exist('data[@alias=("Number","Catalouge Number")]')=1          The column in DB has the data loaded so I cannot add "declare @T table(XMLColumn xml)"

Comment: @Narayana - You should not use `@T`. You should replace `@T` with whatever your table is called. `@T` is just what I used to demonstrate how you can do this.